# doing calculations for values in lists within lists

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists of list.

```
x = [[992,982,...],...,[241,251,...]]
y = [[1184,1178,...],...,[274,294,...]]
```

and I'd like to obtain the angles between x and y as a list of lists

```
angles =[[0.87,0.874,...],...,[0.5,0.52,... ]]
```

My code is the following:

```
angles = []
for i in range(1,10):
    for item1 in x[i]:
        for item2 in y[i]:
            angles.append(np.arctan2(item2, item1))
```

This gives me the angles as a list.

```
angles = [0.87,0.874,...]
```

I would like to have the angles as a list of lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to construct a new list (with appends) at each level of the iteration.  That is, a nesting of list appends to match the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I thought that might be the problem. Do you mean something like: angles = [ ], newlist = [ ], for i in range(1,10):,... ? I'm having trouble imagining at what point I append my sublists to the new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [53]: x = [[992,982],[241,251]]
    ...: y = [[1184,1178],[274,294]]
    ...:
```

Your list iteration:

```
In [56]: angles = []
In [57]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     for item1 in x[i]:
    ...:         for item2 in y[i]:
    ...:             angles.append(math.atan2(item2,item1))
    ...:             
In [58]: angles
Out[58]: 
[0.8734055369251891,
 0.870903457075653,
 0.8783886606617618,
 0.8758910778163088,
 0.8493883488678455,
 0.8841414043445257,
 0.8291796919394373,
 0.8641341374390786]
```

breaking up that list iteration at one level:

```
In [59]: angles = []
In [60]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     alist = []
    ...:     for item1 in x[i]:
    ...:         for item2 in y[i]:
    ...:             alist.append(math.atan2(item2,item1))
    ...:     angles.append(alist)
    ...:             
In [61]: angles
Out[61]: 
[[0.8734055369251891,
  0.870903457075653,
  0.8783886606617618,
  0.8758910778163088],
 [0.8493883488678455,
  0.8841414043445257,
  0.8291796919394373,
  0.8641341374390786]]
```

I could add another level list append to get 2 sets of 2 sets of 2.

The array element pairing only produces 4 values:

```
In [62]: X = np.array(x); Y = np.array(y)
In [63]: np.arctan2(Y,X)
Out[63]: 
array([[0.87340554, 0.87589108],
       [0.84938835, 0.86413414]])
```

I could use broadcasting to get the 8 values

```
In [65]: np.arctan2(Y[:,None,:],X[:,:,None])
Out[65]: 
array([[[0.87340554, 0.87090346],
        [0.87838866, 0.87589108]],

       [[0.84938835, 0.8841414 ],
        [0.82917969, 0.86413414]]])
```

Note that this is a 3d array (2,2,2).

conversely I could get just 4 values from the loops with:

```
In [66]: angles = []
In [67]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     alist = []
    ...:     for item1, item2 in zip(x[i],y[i]):
    ...:         alist.append(math.atan2(item2,item1))
    ...:     angles.append(alist)
    ...:     
    ...:             
In [68]: angles
Out[68]: 
[[0.8734055369251891, 0.8758910778163088],
 [0.8493883488678455, 0.8641341374390786]]
```

When working with scalars `math.atan2` is faster than `np.arctan2`.

Or in list comprehension form:

```
In [72]: [[[math.atan2(item2,item1)] for item1, item2 in zip(x[i],y[i])] for i in range(2)]
Out[72]: 
[[[0.8734055369251891], [0.8758910778163088]],
 [[0.8493883488678455], [0.8641341374390786]]]
```

Comment: Hurraah!! :) The Code in the last box was exactly what I was trying to do. Pure genius! Thank you most kindly. :)

Comment: I added a list comprehension version

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use numpy for the arrays as well.

```
x_arr = np.array(x)
y_arr = np.array(y)
angles_arr = np.arctan2(x_arr, y_arr)
angles = angles_arr.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try this code I get an error "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'atan2' ". I tried the code with 'arctan2' as well, but then I got an error  " 'list' has no attribute 'arctan2' ".

Comment: Sorry, it is `np.arctan2`. That should definitely work.

Comment: I get an error " 'list' object has no attribute 'arctan2' "

Comment: You converted to `np.array`?

Comment: I copied and pasted all of your code into my code and then tried to execute it.

Comment: Ah actually in my code the numbers are floats not integers. So for example x = [[992.2,...],[...],...]. Does that make a difference?